# Restrict XSD attribute value based on another attribute value

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

I have this in the XML:

```xml
<Const Name="a" Value="1.0"/>
<Const Name="b" Value="1"/>
<Const Name="c" Value="A"/>
<Const Name="d" Value="B"/>
```

I have these two cases:

- For a `Const` element with `Name="b"` the `Value` must be one of `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`. No other values are allowed.
- Other `Const` elements may contain other values, as shown.

How do I express that in XSD?

So far I have this:

```xml
<xs:element name="Const">
   <xs:complexType>
       <xs:attribute name="Value" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
       <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I use XSD 1.0, it seems: VS2013... so "Alternative" does not work for me... sadly...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this using XSD 1.1's **[Conditional Type Assignment](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative)**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  vc:minVersion="1.1"> 

  <xs:element name="Const">
    <xs:alternative test="@Name = 'a'" type="aType"/>        
    <xs:alternative                    type="otherType"/>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="aType">
    <xs:sequence/>
      <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:attribute name="Value">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="4"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="otherType">
    <xs:sequence/>
    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Value" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: for your aType I came up with this:<xs:simpleType name="DC1234">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:pattern value="[1234]" />
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>

Comment: Yes, basing `aType` on regular expressions is perfectly valid too.

Answer (score 4):

**Example solution ussing *xs:assert* supposing you're using XSD 1.1**:

```
<xs:element name="Const">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="Value" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:assert test="(@Name='b' and @Value=('1', '2', '3', '4'))
            or
            (@Name='a' and @Value=('1.0', '2.0', '3.0', '4.0'))
            or
            (@Name='c')
            or
            (@Name='d')"></xs:assert>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Note that this is just a example and maybe you have to change it.